# Matplotlib coord. sys origin to top left

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

How can I flip the origin of a matplotlib plot to be in the upper-left corner - as opposed to the default lower-left?  I'm using matplotlib.pylab.plot to produce the plot (though if there is another plotting routine that is more flexible, please let me know).

I'm looking for the equivalent of the matlab command:  axis ij;

Also, I've spent a couple hours surfing matplotlib help and google but haven't come up with an answer.  Some info on where I could have looked up the answer would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For an image or contour plot, you can use the keyword `origin = None | 'lower' | 'upper'` and for a line plot, you can set the ylimits high to low.

```
from pylab import *
A = arange(25)/25.
A = A.reshape((5,5))

figure()
imshow(A, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')

figure()
imshow(A, interpolation='nearest')

d = arange(5)
figure()
plot(d)
ylim(5, 0)

show()
```

Comment: Directly setting the axis limits with "ylim([y1,y2])" or "axis([x1,x2,y1,y2])" worked will.  It's not completely generic, but I'm sure I can figure something out to make it generic.  Maybe the setp command suggested above.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 34):

The easiest way is to use:

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

After you plotted the image. `Origin` works only for `imshow`.

Comment: This worked great when putting maps on satellite imagery with Cartopy. Note that, at least in my use case, this has to run AFTER the `imshow()`.Thanks!

Comment: In case you're using `subplots` and `sharex`/`sharey`, then call this function only once otherwise for even number of cols/rows, you'll end up in the unchanged way again.

Answer (score 13):

`axis ij` just makes the y-axis increase downward instead of upward, right?  If so, then [`matplotlib.axes.invert_yaxis()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.invert_yaxis) might be all you need -- but I can't test that right now.

If that doesn't work, I found [a mailing post](http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg04291.html) suggesting that

```
setp(gca(), 'ylim', reversed(getp(gca(), 'ylim')))
```

might do what you want to resemble `axis ij`.

Comment: I never could get invert_yaxis() to work.  If it did, that would be ideal.  From what I could piece together, the setp command should work, but "reversed" returns an iterator.  I couldn't get it to return a sequence instead, though I am still relatively new to this.  So it may be easy.

Comment: "`axis ij` just makes the y-axis increase downward instead of upward, right?" That is/was not always true: "`axis ij` places the coordinate system origin in the upper-left corner. The `i`-axis is vertical, with values increasing from top to bottom. The `j`-axis is horizontal with values increasing from left to right." (http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/techdoc/ref/axis.html)

Answer (score 8):

The following is a basic way to achieve this

```
ax=pylab.gca()

ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])
```

Answer (score 6):

This

```
plt.ylim(max(plt.ylim()), min(plt.ylim()))
```

has an advantage over this

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

and is that if you are in interactive mode and you repeatedly plot the same plot (maybe with updated data and having a breakpoint after the plot) the y axis won't keep inverting every time.