# Invert an axis in a matplotlib grafic

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I invert the y_axis? Z is a np.array.Thank you

```
Z=TempLake 

X,Y=np.meshgrid(range(Z.shape[0]+1),range(Z.shape[1]+1)) 
im = plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z.transpose(), cmap='hot') 
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal') 
plt.show()
```

I have this:

[image]

I need this:
[image]

Comment: Curtsey of [this](http://old.nabble.com/How-to-reverse-the-direction-of-an-axis--td15170464.html) post, you can either use `ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[::-1])` or [`ax.invert_yaxis()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.invert_yaxis), where `ax` is a `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matplotlib coord. sys origin to top left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349230/matplotlib-coord-sys-origin-to-top-left)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As @Chris said, this can be done with:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Before the 'plt.show()'.

Comment: also, if no other use is intended for `ax`, the one-liner `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()` also works.