# y axis of heat map not inverting in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I'm generating 4 heat maps using subplots and want the y-axis inverted. I'm using `ax[i].invert_yaxis()` but it doesn't seem to be working. An example of the code is below:

```
everything = [data_y_axis, data_length, data_roundness, data_y_SDev]
legend = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title4']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 4, sharex = False, sharey = True, figsize = (13,3))

ax = ax.flatten()

for i, v in enumerate(everything):

    heatmap = ax[i].pcolor(v, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

    ax[i].invert_yaxis()
    ax[i].xaxis.tick_top()
    ax[i].set_xticks(np.arange(v.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)
    ax[i].set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
    ax[i].set_yticks(np.arange(v.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)
    ax[i].set_yticklabels(row_labels, minor=False, fontproperties = titlefont)
    ax[i].set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=False, fontproperties = titlefont)

    cb = fig.colorbar(heatmap, orientation='horizontal', pad=0.02, ax = ax[i])
    cb.set_label(label = legend[i], fontproperties = titlefont)
    cb.outline.set_linewidth(2)
```

The items in `everything` are just np.arrays, all of which have the same shape of (4, 6).

It's currently producing maps like this:[image] and should look like this: [image].

Have I done something obviously wrong?

Comment: Try to move your `invert_yaxis` to the bottom of the set-ticks-axis-stuff-thing.  Maybe `set_yticks` or the other commands are screwing your inversion up?

Comment: Just had a go at what you suggested and it still didn't work I'm afraid!

Comment: For clarity: you want to flip the DATA not the yaxis?  Maybe I misunderstood you first

Comment: Basically the y-axis labels the condition. Heat maps usually (and in this case) plot it like d, c, b, a whereas I want the order to be a, b, c, d. If I plot each one on its own (i.e. without subplots) it does it in the right order... which is what's confusing me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invert an axis in a matplotlib grafic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777381/invert-an-axis-in-a-matplotlib-grafic)

Comment: Thanks for the link (I hadn't seen that), but `ax[i].set_ylim(ax[i].get_ylim()[::-1])` doesn't work either.

Comment: A quickfix might be to either swap the label-list or flip the data up-down (with `numpy.flipud` for example).

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example of your problem?

Comment: Sorted it! I just moved the `ax[i].invert_yaxis()` to after the for loop and now it works for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Aha. I have solved it. I removed `ax[i].invert_yaxis()` from within the `for` loop and stuck it at the end. It now works:

```
for i, v in enumerate(everything):

    heatmap = ax[i].pcolor(v, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

    ax[i].xaxis.tick_top()
    ax[i].set_xticks(np.arange(v.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)
    ax[i].set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
    ax[i].set_yticks(np.arange(v.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)
    ax[i].set_yticklabels(row_labels, minor=False, fontproperties = titlefont)
    ax[i].set_xticklabels(column_labels, minor=False, fontproperties = titlefont)

    cb = fig.colorbar(heatmap, orientation='horizontal', pad=0.02, ax = ax[i])
    cb.set_label(label = legend[i], fontproperties = titlefont)
    cb.outline.set_linewidth(2)

ax[0].invert_yaxis()
```