# python 2D grid plot with origin at left upper corner

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas series with (X,Y) coordinates. I want to plot these points with grid. Both X and Y are in the range of [5,35]. I want to set the origin(0,0) to the left upper corner of the canvas.

Comment: [Matplotlib coord. sys origin to top left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349230/matplotlib-coord-sys-origin-to-top-left)?

Comment: I think you are mistaking this for a code writing service. If you have tried something already, what have you tried, and what was the problem? If you can give a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code, you are more likely to get help here.

Comment: Check the answers to the duplicate question suggested by @Delgan. Alternatively, you could just do `plt.gca().set_ylim([35,0])` - putting 35 at the bottom of your y axis and 0 at the top (i.e. 0,0 is top left)